# Brezis's Proof for compact operators have compact adjoint

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, solution-verification, proof-explanation, compact-operators

This is the proof by Brezis on showing all compact operators have compact adjoints. I am a little bit lost in the last paragraph of the proof:

[image]

**This is how I understood the last paragraph:**

We know that $T^{**} \in K(E^{**}, F^{**})$. Therefore, we have $T^{**}(J_E(B_E)) \subseteq F^{**}$ to have compact closure, where $J_E: E \to E^{**}$ is the canonical injection such that $J_E(x)(f) = f(x)$ for all $f \in E^*$. Now we claim that $J_F(T(B_E)) = T^{**}(J_E(B_E))$, where $J_F$ is the canonical injection for the space $F$. To see this, let $g \in J_F(T(B_E)) \subseteq F^{**}$. Then for $f \in F^*$ and some $x \in B_E$, we have
\begin{align*}
\langle g, f \rangle &= \langle J_F(Tx), f \rangle \\
&= \langle f, Tx \rangle \\
&= \langle T^*f, x \rangle \\
&= \langle J_E x, T^*f \rangle \\
&= \langle T^{**}(J_E x), f \rangle
\end{align*}
where in the last line, we have $g \in T^{**}(J_E(B_E))$. The proof for the converse is similar. Now we know $J_F(F) \subseteq F^{**}$ is closed in $F^{**}$ as $J_F$ is continuous and $F$ is closed. Therefore, we now have:

1. $\overline{J_F(T(B_E))} = \overline{T^{**}(J_E(B_E))} \subseteq F^{**}$ is compact.
2. $J_F(F) \subseteq F^{**}$ is closed.

I am not seeing why 1 and 2 here would imply $\overline{T(B_E)} \subseteq F$ is compact. In particular, it seems like we do not have $F$ to be reflexive and hence $J_F$ does not necessarily have a continuous inverse, which would have mapped compact sets to compact sets and closed sets to closed sets. How do we reach the conclusion that Brezis concluded in the end?

**Update After Reading the Comment:**

$J_F: F \to F^{**}$ is an isometric injection implies that $J_F|_{J(F)}: F \to J(F)$ is an isometric isomorphism. Therefore, we have
$$
J_F|_{J(F)}^{-1}(\overline{J_F(T(B_E))}) = \overline{T(B_E)} \subseteq J_F|_{J(F)}^{-1}(J_F(F)) = F.
$$
Since $J_F|_{J(F)}^{-1}$ is continuous and $\overline{J_F(T(B_E))}$ is compact, we are done.

**Second Update:**
We can also view the problem as such:

If we know $J_F \circ T: E \to F^{**}$ to be compact, then $T: E \to F$ is necessarily compact. Now since $J_F \circ T$ is compact, we have $\overline{J_F(T(B_E))} \subseteq F^{**}$ is compact. Now let $\{ Tx_n \}_n \subseteq T(B_E)$ be a sequence with $\| x_n \| \leq 1$. We show that $\{ Tx_n \}_n$ has a convergent subsequence. Note that we have for the sequence $\{ J_F(T(x_n)) \}_n$ to have a convergent subsequence $\{ J_F(T(x_{n_k})) \}_k$ as $J_F \circ T$ is compact. In particular, this implies that $\{ J_F(T(x_{n_k})) \}_k$ is Cauchy and hence $\{ T(x_{n_k}) \}_k$ is Cauchy. Since $F$ is a Banach space and $T(B_E)$ is closed, we have $\{ T(x_{n_k}) \}_k$ to be a convergent subsequence in $T(B_E)$. This shows that $\overline{T(B_E)} \subseteq F$ is compact. That is, we have $T$ is compact.

I am still, however, not seeing where the condition $J_F(F) \subseteq F^{**}$ is closed being used. I suppose that I did use $T(B_E)$ is closed in the above. Is this what Brezis meant though?

Comment: $J_F$ is an isometric isomorphism. Its inverse, defined on the range, is also an isometric isomorphism .

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you for the comment! I updated the post. Could you check if it is correct? I am not sure why we need $J_F(F) \subseteq F^{**}$ to be closed though. It seems like with this reasoning, we only need the restriction of $J_F$ to be continuous?